# sql query is not showing proper output for my requirement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID,
Year(GetDate())-Year(DOB) as Age,
FirstName+' '+LastName 'HeadOfHousehold',
FamilyFolder.HouseNo
from HouseHoldMembers 
left outer join FamilyFolder on FamilyFolder.FamilyID=HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID
WHERE HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID 
    in (select familyid from HouseHoldMembers where FirstName like 'laxmi')
and HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID like  'alv'+'%'
```

For this i am gettng --Output is:

```
FamilyID         age          HeadOfHousehold              HouseNo  
ALV01L11034A      25             ashoka                        34
ALV01L11034A      74             arpana                        34
ALV01L11034A      62             laxmi                         34
ALV01L11059A      34             shama                         63
ALV01L11059A      62             baby                          63
ALV01L11059A      35             laxmi                         63
```

But,
I want to display like query retreival for maximum age for each familyid (select the familyid accoding to maximum age of that perticular family,output which i wanted to look like is explained below).please give the solution

```
FamilyID          age          HeadOfHousehold              HouseNo  
ALV01L11034A       74                 arpana                   34
ALV01L11059A        62                baby                      63
```

table structure is:
for householdmembers table->

```
memberid varchar(50) as primarykey,firstname varchar(50) as null,lastname varchar(50) as null, relationwithhead varchar(50) as null,familyid varchar(50) as null,dob datetime as null
```

for familyfolder table->

```
familyid varchar(50) as primarykey, houseno varchar(50) as null
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide us with the structure of your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your DBMS supports OLAP functions it's a simple ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID
      ,YEAR(GetDate()) - YEAR(DOB) AS Age
      ,FirstName + ' ' + LastName 'HeadOfHousehold'
      ,FamilyFolder.HouseNo
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY FamilyId ORDER BY YEAR(GetDate()) - YEAR(DOB) DESC
      ) AS rn
    FROM HouseHoldMembers LEFT OUTER JOIN FamilyFolder 
      ON FamilyFolder.FamilyID = HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID
    WHERE
      HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID IN
      (
        SELECT familyid
        FROM HouseHoldMembers
        WHERE FirstName LIKE 'laxmi'
      )
      AND HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID LIKE 'alv' + '%' d`
  ) AS dt
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: The "standard" name (as in "ANSI standard") is "window functions". I think OLAP function is IBM's term for them.

Comment: yep, correct. I'm just used to this name because my Teradata uses it, too :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `max(age)` and `group by(FamilyID)` to get your answer.

Like this:

```
select FamilyID,max(Age) 
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID,Year(GetDate())-Year(DOB) as Age,
FirstName+' '+LastName 'HeadOfHousehold',FamilyFolder.HouseNo
from HouseHoldMembers 
left outer join FamilyFolder 
on FamilyFolder.FamilyID=HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID
WHERE HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID in (select familyid from HouseHoldMembers where FirstName like 'laxmi')
and HouseHoldMembers.FamilyID like  'alv'+'%')
group by FamilyID
```

BTW:I don't test it.

Answer (score 0):

Query if ms sql you ca use this:

```
  SELECT a.FamilyID,
         a.Age,
         a.HeadOfHousehold
         a.HouseNo
  FROM(
  SELECT        hm.FamilyID,
                Year(GetDate())-Year(DOB) AS Age,
                FirstName+' '+LastName AS 'HeadOfHousehold',
                ff.HouseNo,
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hm.FamilyId ORDER BY YEAR(GetDate()) - YEAR(DOB) DESC) as rnk
FROM HouseHoldMembers hm
LEFT OUTER JOIN FamilyFolder ff ON ff.FamilyID=hm.FamilyID
WHERE hm.FirstName = 'laxmi'
  AND hm.FamilyID LIKE 'alv'+'%')a
  WHERE a.rnk = 1
```